# Versioning of REST webservices on top of gRPC

Tags: rest, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've implemented an API service using gRPC with protocol buffers and then used [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) to expose that as a set of REST webservices.

Now I'm getting to the point where I'm having to maintain different versions of the API and I'm stuck.

In my proto file I have a handler like this defined for instance

```
rpc MerchantGet (MerchantRequest) returns (MerchantResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
        get: "/v1.1.0/myapi/merchant/{MerchantID}"
    };
}
```

In my Go code of course I then have a function, `MerchantGet`, to which `GET` actions to `/v1.1.0/myapi/merchant/{MerchantID}` are mapped.

Now, let's say I want to add more functionality to the `MerchantGet` method and release a new version. I intend to maintain backwards compatibility as per the [Semantic Versioning Specification](https://semver.org/) so if I understand correctly that means I can make underlying changes to my `MerchantGet` method and have it supersede the older method as long as it does not require different inputs from the 3rd party (`MerchantRequest`) or change the response sent to the 3rd party (`MerchantResponse`) other than by adding additional fields to the end of the response. (Correct me if I'm wrong in this assumption).

My question is, how do I write proto handlers to serve a method to endpoints of different versions? One option that came to mind would look something as follows:

```
rpc MerchantGet (MerchantRequest) returns (MerchantResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
        get: "/v1.6.0/myapi/merchant/{MerchantID}"
        additional_bindings {
            get: "/v1.5.0/myapi/merchant/{MerchantID}"
        }
        additional_bindings {
            get: "/v1.4.2/myapi/merchant/{MerchantID}"
        }
        additional_bindings {
            get: "/v1.4.1/myapi/merchant/{MerchantID}"
        }
        additional_bindings {
            get: "/v1.4.0/myapi/merchant/{MerchantID}"
        }
        additional_bindings {
            get: "/v1.3.0/myapi/merchant/{MerchantID}"
        }
        additional_bindings {
            get: "/v1.2.0/myapi/merchant/{MerchantID}"
        }
        additional_bindings {
            get: "/v1.1.0/myapi/merchant/{MerchantID}"
        }
    };
}
```

But surely this can't be the idiomatic way of achieving this? It's certainly not very elegant at all as, with each new minor version or patch, I would have to extend these `additional_bindings` to each of my methods (above I'm just using one method as an example).

Comment: Having something that already contains the term RPC in it is a strong indication that what you are doing is not REST. In addition to that, if you need to version your API you are already in RPC land, in REST you'd version the media type (similar as HTML did, i.e. [v4.01](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/), [v5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/)) instead as this is the contract both client and server agree on exchanging messages if they negotiated HTML as the representation format.

Comment: Thanks @RomanVottner but I'm not sure I understand. Yes, these are first and foremost gRPC services and they can indeed be called directly through gRPC. But the whole point of grpc-gateway is to expose gRPC services as REST webservices. And surely one would want to maintain your versioning strategy throughout, just as you would if your underlying services were not RPC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the SemVer spec:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> 3. PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
>
> Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

The only version that matters with respect to REST endpoint versioning is the MAJOR version, because all MINOR and PATCH changes must be backwards-compatible.

To answer your question:
Use only major version numbers in the REST URI.  The rest is an implementation detail, from a REST standpoint.

So, your proto service will be:

```
rpc MerchantGet (MerchantRequest) returns (MerchantResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
        get: "/v1/myapi/merchant/{MerchantID}"
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not clear on what the code for the proto handler would look like then. Considering the input (MerchantRequest) and/or output (MerchantResponse) might differ, I can't just use additional_bindings as in my example in the question. But you've already cleared up a lot of confusion I had about minor versions.

Comment: Changes to `MerchantRequest` and `MerchantResponse` must remain backwards-compatible (remember all fields are optional in proto3, so new fields are always compatible).  Your logic should be able to handle the new (possibly missing) data elements